# 403 Forbidden Error for every directory except Apache DocumentRoot

Tags: php, windows, apache, localhost, http-status-code-403

I installed Apache and php on my local computer.  Now i get the "It works!" message when i go to localhost in my browser and i can even see a sample .php info file.  Yet i get a forbidden error when i attempt to browse to any other directory and any other php file throws an error.  Below is my configuration file, any finger in the right direction is helpful.

http://implicitarts.com/httpd.txt

*was having issues with formatting.

Comment: It's very likely a file permission problem.  I don't know how it works on Windows, but on Linux I'd do `chmod a+x myscript.php`.  I hope there's some conversion.

Comment: did you check the error log and other log files?

Comment: yes, i did.  It confused the mess out of me.  It appears as if the server is getting files from a directory that i did not specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, the issue seemed to be file permissions with files 'copied/dragged' into apaches server directory. I resolved my issue by disabling the UAC checks in windows 7.